# Question 17 in section 2.9 in Schutz's A First Course in General Relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, special-relativity

The question is as follows:

Prove that any timelike vector for which $U^0>0$ and $\vec{U}\cdot \vec{U} = -1$ is the 4-velocity of some world line.

I need to show that there exists a 4-vector $\vec{x}$, s.t $\frac{d\vec{x}}{d\tau} = \vec{U}$, where $\vec{x}$ is a world line of some particle.

So far what I have done is: since $\vec{U}\cdot \frac{d\vec{U}}{d\tau} = 0$, so we have:

$$dU^0/d\tau = U^1/U^0 dU^1/d\tau + U^2/U^0dU^2/d\tau + U^3/U^0 dU^3/d\tau$$

I used the fact that $U^0>0$, so I can divide by it above.

We also have: $dx^\mu/d\tau = U^\mu $. How to continue? Any ideas?

Comment: This is not homework, I am not taking any courses; I am self studying this stuff. (if I were to ask questions from MTW would it be HW also?).

Comment: Yes, it would.${}$

Comment: Anybody teaches nowadays courses from MTW? more than 1000 pages book. :-D

Comment: @JohnRennie See this is why we need to rename the homework policy.

Comment: If $\mathbf{U}$ is timelike there is a frame in which we can write $\mathbf{U} = (U^0,0,0,0)$. If $\eta_{\alpha\beta}U^\alpha U^\beta=-1$ then in this frame $\mathbf{U} = (1,0,0,0)$. Since this is the four velocity of a stationary observer that means $\mathbf{U}$ is a four velocity.

Comment: @JohnRennie this seems circular since in a followup question I am asked to "Use this to prove that for any timelike vector $\vec{V}$ there's a Lorentz frame in which $\vec{V}$ has zero spatial components". Which is what you wrote in your last comment, right?

Comment: Ah, yes OK, obviously Schutz wants a different proof.

Comment: Hi MathematicalPhysicist. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the candidate four velocity:

$$ \mathbf{U} = \left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}, \frac{dx}{d\tau}, \frac{dy}{d\tau}, \frac{dz}{d\tau}\right) $$

and write this as:

$$ \mathbf{U} = \frac{dt}{d\tau}\left(1, \frac{dx}{dt}, \frac{dy}{dt}, \frac{dz}{dt}\right) = \frac{dt}{d\tau}\left(1, \vec{v}\right) $$

where $t, x, y, z$ are some convenient coordinates and $\vec{v}$ is the **coordinate** velocity in these coordinates. If the velocity is less than $c$, i.e. if the worldline is timelike we know:

$$ \frac{dt}{d\tau} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2}} $$

which is greater than zero, and if we calculate the inner product we get:

$$ \eta_{\alpha\beta} U^\alpha U^\beta = \frac{1}{1 - v^2}\left(-1 + v^2 \right) = -1 $$